# How to improve firebase real time database rules with anonymous user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I have a simple json tree like this : https://ibb.co/Rgpznd0, and my rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".write": "false",  
  }
}
```

I only need to read the data from the database, i retrieve the token from the user

```
const accessToken = await user.getIdToken();
```

and i do a get request with this url with axios:

> [https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/${query}.json?auth=${accessToken}](https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/$%7Bquery%7D.json?auth=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

this work, but i get some warning from firebase about security rules

///////////////////////////////

UPDATE

I tried to put the rules like this, in a more secure way :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "destinations": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing the url like this:

> [https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/destinations.json/${uid}?auth=${accessToken}](https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/destinations.json/$%7Buid%7D?auth=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

But now the axios request doesn't work even if i put the uid in the query.

I also tried on postman and the response it's seems the html of the page, I am doing something wrong.

How can i do that? And get a json response?

////////////

UPDATE 2

full url like requested

> [https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/destinations.json/nQhLc86TWHeHhSP7JSuPAJdBKyk1?auth=${accessToken}](https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/destinations.json/nQhLc86TWHeHhSP7JSuPAJdBKyk1?auth=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

UPDATE 3

I have find a solution to my problem, you can check the answer below

Comment: We can't see that your `query` variable matches the data that's being protected by the rules.  Please edit the question show a hard-coded URL that you've tried, without a variable for the path to the data.  Also I suggest removing your first question about the security rule warning and instead focus on the new problem, otherwise people might get confused what your question is asking.

Comment: i put an hard coded url without uid and accessToken, they are too long. I have removed the first question, thanks, do you think the rules are ok now?

Comment: I'm asking for you to show the query variable, not the ID token.  We can't see the path that you code is trying to read, and see that it matches your security rules.

Comment: In the query params i put the name of the json tree, only that.
For example [databaseurl]/crew.json/uid?=auth, not any of the params that i can find here [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-query-parameters)

Maybe i need to use some?

Comment: Please show the full URL you are using, without access token, in the question itself.  It should be clear what data you are expecting to access, and that it matches the rules you've written to allow that access.

Comment: Now your URL has a different variable in it, and it doesn't look correctly placed for the data you want to access.  As it's written now, I would never expect this query to return any data you show in your database.

Comment: if for example i need the data inside the 'destinations', how i need to write the query?
My database tree is this : https://imgbb.com/Rgpznd0

Comment: I upload my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this guide: https://medium.com/@skytreasure/easy-way-to-secure-firebase-realtime-database-with-rules-when-you-have-anonymous-sign-in-or-already-e8ff1ddfbfc9

Inside the onAuthStateChanged i set a request to the database with the secure key

```
 await set(
                ref(
                  db,
                  `/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_ROUTE}/${user.uid}`
                ),
                true
              )
                .then(() => {
                  //Fullfilled
                })
                .catch((error: Error) => {
                  throw new Error(error.message);
                });
```

[image: FIREBASE RULES]

Then i didn't change the other methods to fetch.

> [https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/${query}.json?auth=${accessToken}](https://discover-planets-to-visit-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/$%7Bquery%7D.json?auth=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

Instead of query i put: 'destination' - 'crew' - 'technology' depends of witch pages do you go.

Now the database is secure, only who have the anonymous id can do the request